# Kendo UI DropDownList Filter Not Filtering

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I type in the filter "chef", the filter is applied and I select any item. I re-opened the dropdown and typed the same filter again no request is made. Am I missing something ? (the same issue happen with client filtering)

URL : http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/serverfiltering

Comment: Without seeing some code of what you have tried to do you aren't really going to get any useful answers. If you are using server filtering have you set up a read action for the dropdown and are you sending the filter value back to the server. Again some code would help to investigate the issue.

Comment: @DavidShorthose I have already mentioned this issue occured with client filtering also and I am testing the same example online at http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/serverfiltering nothing special just typing a filter, selecting an item and re-typing the same filter again and the filter not applied

Comment: Yes but without knowing how you have set up the control and how your server side data is working then it is near impossible to help you out. If you have some sample data then I can try to help. The first thing that comes to mind is it may be caching the data for the control so what happens if you disable caching in the browser does it work as the demo you have provided works fine for me across multiple browsers and machines. Have you tried to use fiddler to see if the server side implementation is being fired off the second time?

Comment: @DavidShorthose I am testing the example live on demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/serverfiltering not localy on my machine, and the server request is not fired although the same issue appear with client filtering

Comment: What browser are you using and have you looked at the developer tools to see if any errors are being thrown.

Comment: @DavidShorthose latest chrome version "Version 39.0.2171.95 m" and no error in developper tools console

Comment: If you do a search for chef and then try then searching for chai does that work. Also if you selected the first chef item and then continued typing chef and then added a space this should then force the server to do another call back. Because the first item it picks up the datasource already knows what this is and is the selected item. If you edit the example and change the filtering to "contains" rather than start with then the text changes are sent back to the server everytime when inspecting with fiddler. So what you are experiencing is expected behaviour. It just isn't obvious.

Comment: @DavidShorthose https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/479 it seems to be a bug

Comment: Ah ok. Well at least you have an answer now which is good. It's not a scenario I had encountered or any of my users have seen before but I guess it's handy to know that it is an issue and being addressed in the next service pack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the widget. It is solved [Link](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/479)

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line "serverFiltering: true" for me it solve problem and now typing value in dropdownlist input working.